# Export/Import LDAP Ldif file with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can I export or import contacts using this format from either the Active Directory or Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special cmdlet for that but you can run the traditional tool, ldifde, from within PowerShell.